# Web Scraping - Get the 'blahblah' out from <td foo=blahblah>TEXT</td> using bs4?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a few schedule tables from ESPN: http://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/20171001

```
import requests
import bs4

response = requests.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/20171001')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print soup.prettify()

table = soup.find_all('table')

data = []
for i in table:
    rows = i.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [col.text.strip() for col in cols]
        data.append([col for col in cols if col])
```

My code works fine except the output is missing the date info:

```
[
    "Phoenix PHX", 
    "Utah UTAH", 
    "394 tickets available from $6"
], 
[], 
[
    "Miami MIA", 
    "Orlando ORL", 
    "1,582 tickets available from $12"
]
```

After some investigation, I realized that the date and time information is wrapped within the  tags like so:

```
<td data-behavior="date_time" data-date="2017-10-07T23:00Z"><a data-dateformat="time1" href="/nba/game?gameId=400978807" name="&amp;lpos=nba:schedule:time"></a></td>
```

I see this on other websites from time to time as well but never really understood why they do it this way. How can I extract text inside an open tag to get the "2017-10-07T23:00Z" in my output?

Answer (score 1):

attrs property contains a dictionary of attributes which you can utilize to fetch values,I have added a length check as some empty rows are present.

Can you try modifying the for loop as below:

```
for i in table:
    rows = i.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        date_data = None
        if len(cols) > 2:
            date_data = cols[2].attrs['data-date']
        cols = [col.text.strip() for col in cols]
        dat = [col for col in cols if col]
        if date_data:
            dat.append(date_data)
        data.append(dat)
```

PS: the above snippet can be optimized :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some `td` tags in that table contain [attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). You can access a `td`'s attributes by calling `attrs()` which returns a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
>>> td = soup.select('tr')[1].select('td')[2]
>>> td
<td data-behavior="date_time" data-date="2017-10-01T22:00Z"><a data-dateformat="time1" href="/nba/game?gameId=400978817" name="&amp;lpos=nba:schedule:time"></a></td>
>>> td.attrs
{'data-date': '2017-10-01T22:00Z', 'data-behavior': 'date_time'}
>>> td.attrs['data-date']
'2017-10-01T22:00Z'
```

To that end, you can create a function that returns the date if that attribute is present or just return the text for a `td`:

```
import requests
import bs4

def date_or_text(td):
    if 'data-date' in td.attrs:
        return td.attrs['data-date']
    return td.text

def extract_game_information(tr):
    tds_with_blanks = (date_or_text(td) for td in tr.select('td'))
    return [data for data in tds_with_blanks if data]

response = requests.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/20171001')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

data = [extract_game_information(tr) for tr in soup.select('tr')]
```